# Realm Wrong transactional state (no active transaction, wrong type of transaction, or transaction already in progress)

Tags: android, android-studio, transactions, realm

I am using Realm for android and the error log does not show any error trace  inside my project.

My logcat output looks like this:

```
Process: com.toyanathpatro.gurkha, PID: 7600
    io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Wrong transactional state (no active transaction, wrong type of transaction, or transaction already in progress) in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 157
        at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.nativeAdvanceRead(Native Method)
        at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.advanceRead(SharedGroup.java:83)
        at io.realm.internal.ImplicitTransaction.advanceRead(ImplicitTransaction.java:35)
        at io.realm.internal.SharedGroupManager.advanceRead(SharedGroupManager.java:76)
        at io.realm.HandlerController.realmChanged(HandlerController.java:384)
        at io.realm.HandlerController.handleMessage(HandlerController.java:116)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Hi, All write operations (adding, modifying, and removing objects) must be wrapped in write transactions. Also nested transactions are not allowed. Posting the code that generated this stack can help identify the issue.

Comment: There are a lot of realm expressions i am using , please give sometime i am   trying to figure this out.

Comment: From your limited description it sounds like you are trying to write to Realm outside of a transaction. Perhaps have a look at this issue from the Github https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2462

Comment: yeah seems like so i am fixing my code